# Concurrency problems in netty application

Tags: concurrency, netty

I implemented a simple http server [link](https://github.com/tsopot/project), but the result of the test (`ab -n 10000 -c 100 http://localhost:8080/status`) is very bad (look through the test.png in the previous link)
I don't understand why it doesn't work correctly with multiple threads.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that, by default, Netty's default thread pool is configured with as many threads as there are cores on the machine. The idea being to handle requests asynchronously and non-blocking (where possible).

Your `/status` test includes a database transaction which blocks because of the intrinsic design of database drivers etc. So your performance - at high level - is essentially a result of:-

a.) you are running a pretty hefty test of 10,000 requests attempting to run 100 requests in parallel
b.) you are calling into a database for each request so this is will not be quick (relatively speaking compared to some non-blocking I/O operation)

A couple of questions/considerations for you:-

1. **Machine Spec.?**
   What is the spec. of the machine you are running your application and test on?
   How many cores?
   If you only have 8 cores available then you will only have 8 threads running in parallel at any time. That means those batches of 100 requests per time will be queueing up
2. **Consider what is running on the machine during the test**
   It sound like you are running the application AND Apache Bench on the same machine so be aware that both your application and the testing tool will both be contending for those cores (this is in addition to any background processes going on also contending for those cores - such as the OS)
3. **What will the load be?**
   Predicting load is difficult right. If you do think you are likely to have 100 requests into the database at any one time then you may need to think about:-
   a. your production environment may need a couple of instance to handle the load
   b. try changing the config. of Netty's default thread pool to increase the number of threads
   c. think about your application architecture - can you cache any of those results instead of going to the database for each request

Comment: there are 2 cores and ability to work with 4 threads in parallel. I think that the main trouble is really in not async database calls as Frederic wrote before.

Comment: So you have 1 hyperthreaded CPU with 2 cores. You load test is way too big for this machine then. Making database calls async rather than sync will not improve your situation - it will probably make it worse. Just by making a blocking call asynchronous does not make it more efficient. I think you just need to get a better handle on what is going on at a high-level to service 1 of your test requests, an understanding of asynchronous, blocking, non-blocking, Netty architecture etc.

Comment: ty for your answer, I'll try to do my best!

Comment: You're welcome. Take pride at least that you are attempting to test the performance of your application - which is a task all too many developers do not factor into their life-cycle (at least in my experience).

Answer (score 0):

May be linked to the usage of Database access (synchronous task) within one of your handler (at least in your TrafficShappingHandler) ?

You might need to "make async" your database calls (other threads in a producer/consumer way for instance)...

If something else, I do not have enough information...